# Prevent removal of <link></link> with html_sanitize()

Tags: javascript, html, html-sanitizing

I'm using html_sanitize() on the client side to sanitize HTML for security purposes. However, the styles of different elements are not the same as the ones I'm receiving before being sanitized. I need to keep what's within the tags and I'm trying to figure out how.

As an example, I receive the following HTML:

```
<div>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script> alert('Blah');</script>
<a class="btn-active"></a>
</div>
```

And html_sanitize(bodyHtml, urlX, idX); returns:

```
<div>
<a class="btn-active"></a>
</div>
```

Ideally, I want to keep the link tags with everything else the same. Like so.

```
<div>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<a class="btn-active"></a>
</div>
```

I've been trying to find a solution everywhere but I can't. I've also looked at the documentation, implemented a custom policy, but even then I can't control the script tags from getting deleted.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you look at the documentation? there must be some options to add escape strings or something like that.

Comment: yes i looked at documentation but nothing fuitful i found.

Comment: Can you share the documentation of your html_sanitize, its not clear if it is the php one, the npm one...

Comment: i followed this documentation and tried to apply `clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: sanitizeHtml.defaults.allowedTags.concat([ 'img' ])
});` but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html#node-recommended) you can do something like :

```
// Allow only a super restricted set of tags and attributes
clean = sanitizeHtml(dirty, {
  allowedTags: [ 'link' ],
  allowedAttributes: {
    'link': [ 'href','rel','type' ]
  }
});
```

With `dirty = document.documentElement.innerHTML;` (for exemple).

You'll have of course to change `dirty` by `clean` to finish the work :

`document.documentElement.innerHTML = clean;`

Comment: I think this will override the AllowedTags array. So you should define all the tags in the array. I am not sure tho.

Comment: I replaced `sanitizeHtml` from `html_sanitize`. Now i am getting `ReferenceError: dirty is not defined` error. Any idea?

Comment: I guess it won't work with `html_sanitize` function?

Comment: What is `html_sanitize` ? Share your doc if its not the npm one.

Comment: I have done it like this, but not working.
`$('#id').val(html_sanitize($('#id').val(), urlX, idX), {
            allowedTags: [ 'link' ],
            allowedAttributes: {
              'link': [ 'href','rel','type' ]
            }
          });`

Comment: You don't understand my question. I can't help you properly If I don't know where do you take from `html_sanitize()` function its not a native function of javascript or jQuery. If it is from npm (the documentation I've shared) you must do it in multiple step; as I've shown in my answer but must include the library before if it not the case.

Comment: I am refering this document https://github.com/google/caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer and this https://github.com/google/caja/wiki/CajaWhitelists for whitelisting elements. it's ofGoogle Caja.